# How to get a text in tag with casperjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a html-code:

```
<div class="div_table_body">
<table class="part_listing">
    <tr><td>sometext</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sometext2</td></tr>
    ...
</table>
</div>
```

I try to get a text in tag 'td' with casperjs:

```
function getLinks() {
    var tr = document.querySelectorAll('div.div_table_body table.part_listing tr');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(tr, function (e) {
        return e.getHTML('td', true);
        });
    }
    casper.then(function () {
        links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
        console.log('links ' +links);
        });
```

But I get a NULL, please help to understand what in this code is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will update `getLinks` to create and return an area containing outerHTML strings for the td. You can't use the `getHTML()` inside `getLinks`. Casper evaluates the `getLinks` and executes this on a page, so that needs to be vanilla JS.

```
function getLinks() {
    var tr = document.querySelectorAll('div.div_table_body table.part_listing tr'); 
    return Array.prototype.map.call(tr, function (e) {
        return e.querySelector('td').outerHTML;
    });
}
```

To fetch with Casper only:

```
casper.start('http://www.example.com', function() {
    this.getHTML('div.div_table_body table.part_listing tr > td', true); 
});
```

I updated your selector to select `td`s from the `tr`s.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to Easily Get Text Content with CasperJS:

CasperJS allows you to access the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of elements using [`getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) and its corresponding `.text` attribute:

**Short Answer:**

```
var td = this.getElementsInfo('.div_table_body > .part_listing > tbody > tr > td');
this.echo(td[0].text); // Result: sometext
```

**Full Answer:**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://www.example.com/', function () {
  var td = this.getElementsInfo('.div_table_body > .part_listing > tbody > tr > td');
  var td_array = [].map.call(td, function (element) {
    return element.text.trim();
  });
  
  this.echo(td_array); // Result: sometext,sometext2
});

casper.run();
```

This will return an array containing `[sometext, sometext2]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer